# reveal.js: is there a native way to insert a string in a presentation, starting from a data file?

Tags: reveal.js

Imagine I have a JSON (or another data file) as this:

```json
{"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"}
```

And Imagine I want to put in one of my slide something like

```
<!-- .slide: data-file="./input.json" -->

## The number is ${.foo}

My example test
```

to have

```
## The number is 42

My example test
```

Is there a way to do it? Is there some `hello world` example?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Get value from JSON and Place into HTML

To get the JSON from javascript you can send an XML request and then put the data into the slide via javascript:

```
<section id="slide1">The Number is 0</section>
<script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("slide1").innerHTML = "The number is " + data.foo;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "input.json", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

If you just want to put the `foo` value into only part of your slide, you can create a `<span></span>` element inside your slide and change the `id` attribute:

```
<section>
    <span id="slide1">The number is 0</span><br>
    My example test
</section>
```

:)

Comment: How to insert  in the slide the link to the file? Thank you

Comment: @aborruso What link? Like what is the address from your javascript? Is it stored in a variable

Comment: I must use this in a reveal.js presentation, not in a generic webpage. For this reason in my example I write `<!-- .slide: data-file="./input.json" -->`

Comment: @aborruso I have editted it now. Is it something like this you want?